# Open source absolute atmospheric corrections for Sentinel-2

Tags: open-source-gis, sentinel-2, atmospheric-correction, sen2cor

I am searching for open source absolute atmospheric correction processors for Sentinel-2. There are many of proprietary ones (FLAASH, QUACS, MACCS) which I cannot use for my study.

Beside DOS1 (QGIS SCP plugin), Sen2Cor (SNAP) and the upcoming new 6S/ATCORR (GRASS), are there any other absolute atmospheric correction processors for Sentinel-2 imagery available in open source software packages?

Comment: Are you searching an absolute atmospheric correction? Because for relative, you have R, python, OTB, and so on...

Comment: Am searching for absolute correction models, which are already "ready-to-go", as they need just the parameters and they process it. The data source would be 1C level.

Comment: MACCS has been renamed MAJA, it is still not open source, but it is freely available as binary code. Personally I'd like to make it available open source and am working at it, I need to convince people in CNES. Anyway, you can download it from https://logiciels.cnes.fr/en/content/maja . If you need to use it commercially, it would also be available for free but you would need to contact me.

Comment: Thank you @O.Hagolle for the info! It would be really great to have it open source. I never tested both as I struggled to install MACCS on CentOS for testing purposes of the Sen2-Agri system (but this is another story in progress). I don't need it commercially but for research (as an institute project) and I am searching for all the open source platforms that can help me, as ENVI etc. are not available and I woul like to compare the results for our area of interest.

Comment: There is also ARCSI (http://rsgislib.org/arcsi/) which is based on 6S like i.atcorr in GRASS GIS is (https://grass.osgeo.org/grass75/manuals/i.atcorr.html).